# Inline-block white space fix not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create "floating" columns using inline blocks (as I am sick of floating left with clearfix). Everywhere I read, a way to get rid of the white space with inline blocks is to use `word-spacing : -4px` or negative margin of -4px. But, for me -4px is not fixing the issue. Why is that?

See tiny white space visible in Chrome at 100% browser zoom:

[image]

See random spaces at 110% zoom

[image]

My html is:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col1">col 1</div>
        <div class="col1">col 1</div>
        <div class="col1">col 1</div>
        <div class="col1">col 1</div>
        <div class="col1">col 1</div>
        <div class="col1">col 1</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-wrap {word-spacing : -4px;}
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4, .col5, .col6, .col7, .col8, .col9, .col10, .col11, .col12, .col13, .col14, .col15, .col16, .col17, .col18 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color:#eee;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.col9 {width: 50%;}
```

**EDITED**: Potential solutions:
-5px fixes, but I am not sure what new issues that would introduce.

Comment: It's to do with the space glyph metrics of the font you're using, as well as the way the browser resolves sub-pixel values, because the 4px is just an approximation for common proportionally spaced fonts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Inline-block:** whitespace surrounding inline-block elements becomes
>   relevant, it behaves just like text.

I suggest three solutions to overcome this issue(probably there are more):

1)Solution using `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block`

```css
.content-wrap {
  word-spacing: -4px;
}
.col1,
.col2,
.col3,
.col4,
.col5,
.col6,
.col7,
.col8,
.col9,
.col10,
.col11,
.col12,
.col13,
.col14,
.col15,
.col16,
.col17,
.col18 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  
}
.col9 {
  width: 50%;
}
.row{
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
</div>
```

2)Solution using `font-size: 0` to parent and desire to child:

```css
.content-wrap {
  word-spacing: -4px;
}
.col1,
.col2,
.col3,
.col4,
.col5,
.col6,
.col7,
.col8,
.col9,
.col10,
.col11,
.col12,
.col13,
.col14,
.col15,
.col16,
.col17,
.col18 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.col9 {
  width: 50%;
}
.row{
  font-size: 0;  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
</div>
```

3)Solution using `flex`:

```css
.content-wrap {
  word-spacing: -4px;
}
.col1,
.col2,
.col3,
.col4,
.col5,
.col6,
.col7,
.col8,
.col9,
.col10,
.col11,
.col12,
.col13,
.col14,
.col15,
.col16,
.col17,
.col18 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.col9 {
  width: 50%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col1">col 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can say I prefer the font-size:0 on parent. Can just get a tiny bit annoying to make sure you specify a font for the children elements. Usually I add `parent-element * { // reset font size }`

Comment: I am not ready to use flex because of browser support. I will experiment with font 0, I want to make sure the Safari bug listed here is not an issue anymore: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: PS. 5px fixes, but I am not sure what new issues that would introduce.

Comment: My suggestion is to use `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a float instead, and you could also clean up your css and select all columns starting with 'col' like so.

```
div[class^='col'],div[class*='col']{
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```